# T-SQL update multi row using a where statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, where-clause

Lets say I create a DB with tables for a movie rental data Base. I have a table called `customer` and in this table I have `late_fees` and `PK_Customer_ID` attributes.

What I am trying to do is on a promotion waive 20% off total late fees. I would like to select the customers that are getting this late fee reduction.

What I have so far is

```
update Customers
set Customer_Balance_Due = (Customer_Balance_Due -(Customer_Balance_Due * .20))
where PK_Customer_ID = 1;
select * from Customers
```

What I would like to do is add multiple PK_Customer_ID values in the `WHERE` clause. Is this possible in one statement like this or would I need to write each one out when I do an update like this?

I think in the end it would be better to do a where Customer_Balance_Due >  0 that way it automatically selects customers that have a valid balance. but for the sake of asking. Can you do a single statement multi row update?

when adding commas in the where statement that would give an incorrect syntax error so that would not work I was hoping the syntax would be right and it would allow me to write out a large update in a one line statement.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a condition like this:

```
WHERE PK_Customer_ID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Wow that was so fast thank you so much, obviously I have a lot left to learn. Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: 'update Customers
set Customer_Balance_Due = (Customer_Balance_Due -(Customer_Balance_Due * .20))
WHERE Customer_Balance_Due > 5
select * from Customers' this is what I ended up doing as a discount program which was cool